# Connecting PunchThrough LightBlue Bean/Arduino Uno to Android app

Tags: java, android, eclipse, arduino, arduino-ide

I am trying to connect the Punch Through Light Blue Bean to an Android app. Simply. I want to send the data that the Bean collects to an app that analyzes it and displays graphical feedback.

Right now I am trying to get an Arduino Uno to send back data from a piezo force sensor and an MCU 6050 accelerometer to Eclipse so I can manipulate the data and display the result.

I want to have the Arduino register when I touch the piezo sensor and at that moment of contact, record the gyroscope data and accelerometer data. Then in Eclipse I simply want to run the data through some Iterations and define the action. From here I would like to display the data in an Android App but I'm just trying to get this to work right now.

So far this is the code I have for the Accel/Gyro

```
#include<Wire.h>
const int MPU_addr=0x68;  // I2C address of the MPU-6050
int16_t AcX,AcY,AcZ,Tmp,GyX,GyY,GyZ;
void setup(){
  Wire.begin();
  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU_addr);
  Wire.write(0x6B);  // PWR_MGMT_1 register
  Wire.write(0);     // set to zero (wakes up the MPU-6050)
  Wire.endTransmission(true);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop(){
  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU_addr);
  Wire.write(0x3B);  // starting with register 0x3B (ACCEL_XOUT_H)
  Wire.endTransmission(false);
  Wire.requestFrom(MPU_addr,14,true);  // request a total of 14 registers
  AcX=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x3B (ACCEL_XOUT_H) & 0x3C (ACCEL_XOUT_L)     
  AcY=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x3D (ACCEL_YOUT_H) & 0x3E (ACCEL_YOUT_L)
  AcZ=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x3F (ACCEL_ZOUT_H) & 0x40 (ACCEL_ZOUT_L)
  Tmp=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x41 (TEMP_OUT_H) & 0x42 (TEMP_OUT_L)
  GyX=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x43 (GYRO_XOUT_H) & 0x44 (GYRO_XOUT_L)
  GyY=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x45 (GYRO_YOUT_H) & 0x46 (GYRO_YOUT_L)
  GyZ=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  // 0x47 (GYRO_ZOUT_H) & 0x48 (GYRO_ZOUT_L)

 Serial.print("AcX = "); Serial.print(AcX);
 Serial.print(" | AcY = "); Serial.print(AcY);
 Serial.print(" | AcZ = "); Serial.print(AcZ);
 Serial.print(" | Tmp = "); Serial.print(Tmp/340.00+36.53);  //equation for     temperature in degrees C from datasheet

 Serial.print(" | GyX = "); Serial.print(GyX);
 Serial.print(" | GyY = "); Serial.print(GyY);
 Serial.print(" | GyZ = "); Serial.println(GyZ);
 delay(500);
}
```

I am going to add the piezo code but I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions for going from arduino to android studio or eclipse in between...